# Promise inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have trying to do a bunch of database insertion and selection using a promisfied `mysql` library.

The problem is that I have to use a for loop.

My code looks like this:

```
var partNumber = [],
        stageName = [],
        quantity = [],
        locationName = []
    var orderType, receiveDate, customerName

    pool.query(`select * from orderDetail where orderID = ${req.body.orderID} order by orderDetailID`)
        .then(mainrow => {
            
            for (let i = 0; i < mainrow.length; i++) {
                
                    quantity.push(mainrow[i].QtyShipped)
                     pool.query(`Select PartNumber from parts where partID = ${mainrow[i].PartID}`)

                    .then(rows => {
                        console.log(`here is 1`)
                        partNumber.push(rows[0].PartNumber)
                    
                        return pool.query(`Select StageName from stages where StageID = ${mainrow[i].StageID}`)
                    })
                    .then(rows => {
                        console.log(`here is 2`)
                        
                        return pool.query(`Select LocationName from locations where locationID =${mainrow[i].LocationID}`)
                    })
                    .then(rows=>{
                        console.log(` here is 3`)
                        locationName.push(rows[0].LocationName)
                        
                        stageName.push(rows[0].LocationName)
                        orderType=mainrow[i].OrderType
                        receiveDate = mainrow[0].receiveDate
                        req.flash('success', `You returned back to the OrderID ${req.body.orderID}`)
                        customerName = mainrow[0].CustomerName
                        if(i==mainrow.length-1){
                            var query = queryString.stringify({
                                "orderID": req.body.orderID,
                                "orderType": orderType,
                                "date": receiveDate,
                                "customerName": customerName,
                                "success": req.flash('success'),
                                "partNumber": partNumber,
                                "quantity": quantity,
                                "locationName": locationName,
                                "stageName": stageName
                
                            })
                            
                            res.redirect('/orderDetails?' + query)
                            
                        }
                        
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                    })

                    
            }
            
        })
        

        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

The parent query is where I am retrieving the orderID and I am looping through various orderID's to retrieve orderDetails and populate array. However, I am having a really hard time keeping this code synchronous inside the for loop.

I want the `console.log` to be:

```
here is 1
here is 2
here is 3

here is 1
here is 2 
here is 3

here is 1
here is 2 
here is 3
```

Instead I am getting:

```
here is 1
here is 2
here is 1
here is 1
 here is 3
here is 2
here is 2
 here is 3
 here is 3
```

Each async code is executing the correct number of time in this case 3 but it is not synchronous at all because of the for loop. Is there a way to use async code inside for loop and have it be synchronous?

Comment: consider using async-await

Comment: Use `async/await` if you want to write asynchronous code as if it was synchronous.

Comment: Also, you should use prepared statements instead of template literals for queries to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code rewritten with `async/await`. Just keep in mind that with such approach you will execute each request one after another instead of doing it in parallel as you did with promises. So this solution is slower. Also as **zero298** pointed out you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

```js
const partNumber = []
const stageName = []
const quantity = []
const locationName = []
let orderType, receiveDate, customerName
try {
  const mainrow = await pool.query(`select * from orderDetail where orderID = ${req.body.orderID} order by orderDetailID`)
  for (let i = 0; i < mainrow.length; i++) {
    quantity.push(mainrow[i].QtyShipped)
    let rows = await pool.query(`Select PartNumber from parts where partID = ${mainrow[i].PartID}`)
    console.log(`here is 1`)
    partNumber.push(rows[0].PartNumber)
    rows = await pool.query(`Select StageName from stages where StageID = ${mainrow[i].StageID}`)
    console.log(`here is 2`)
    rows = await pool.query(`Select LocationName from locations where locationID =${mainrow[i].LocationID}`)
    console.log(` here is 3`)
    locationName.push(rows[0].LocationName)
    stageName.push(rows[0].LocationName)
    orderType = mainrow[i].OrderType
    receiveDate = mainrow[0].receiveDate
    req.flash('success', `You returned back to the OrderID ${req.body.orderID}`)
    customerName = mainrow[0].CustomerName
  }
  const query = queryString.stringify({
    "orderID": req.body.orderID,
    "orderType": orderType,
    "date": receiveDate,
    "customerName": customerName,
    "success": req.flash('success'),
    "partNumber": partNumber,
    "quantity": quantity,
    "locationName": locationName,
    "stageName": stageName

  })
  res.redirect('/orderDetails?' + query)
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop goes through all its iterations right away, making all the top level queries.

By the time you reach the end of the `for` loop, you have as many asynchronous DB requests working in the background as the number of iterations.

There is no guarantee that all the promises of the first iteration are resolved before the promises from subsequent iterations are resolved.

In short, the `for` loop doesn't wait until any of the promises are resolved.

Solution - use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```
for (let i = 0; i < mainrow.length; i++) {

   await pool.query(foo);
   await pool.query(bar);
}
```

This is one (and most preferred) way to solve it.